# Saving data from textarea to database in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I´m looking for a way to save data from an input field to database.

Now, on the HTML-page is a simple **textarea**-Field. If the user presses the button to save the data a javascript function executed.

This javascript function get´s the data from the textarea with this statement:

```
test = $('#test1').val();
```

And then it will be given to the php-function with this statement.

```
 $.get(url+"test/saveTest/"+test, function (o){ 
        //Do something
  });
```

It works, but if I add a linebreak in textarea it will be lost.

Anybody nows a solution? Or an alternative to textarea-input field?

https://jsfiddle.net/c7y0p6jw/

Comment: thats not how you send over data. Please read about GET and POST requests

Comment: Use put or post, not get to pass and save data. It is very bad idea to use get to manipulate data.

Comment: Tried to use `encodeURIComponent` , it is safe to use ...

Comment: I thought it was a good Idea, because I want to get the data back to proof if the php function was succeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$.get` I would recomend to use `$.post` or `$.ajax` because `$.get` is like the name says to **get** data not to **post** data.

Ajax example

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url + "test/saveTest/",
    data: {'test': test},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (){
        // do what you want when the submit was successfully
    },
});
```

PHP

```
$test = json_decode($_POST['test']);
```

For the problem with displaying the line breaks you can output your database field by using

```
echo nl2br(DATABASE FIELD);
```

Comment: I thought it was a good Idea, because I want to get the data back to proof if the php function was succeded.

Comment: You can return data in you php function and can use the returned data inside the `success function`

Comment: Okay, thanks :)! But your answer is not the whole answer of my question bescause the text wouldn´t be saved in formatted text. (such as linebreaks,..)